# Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've got an issue with an imported project in eclipse :

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for fr.su:publipostage:1.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.13.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 10 -> [Help 2]

> Here is my POM.XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.su</groupId>
    <artifactId>publipostage</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity</artifactId>
            <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx</artifactId>
            <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.xwpf</artifactId>
            <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <xdocreport.version>2.0.1</xdocreport.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> My settings.xml in .m2 folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<settings NS1:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/settings/1.0.0" xmlns:NS1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <!-- identification pour les telechargements -->
    <server>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
    </server>

    <!-- identification pour les deploiements -->
    <server>
        <id>applicatifs-releases</id>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>applicatifs-snapshots</id>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've already looked in a lot of threads talking about this subject but nothing worked so far.

Comment: "connect timed out" indicates a networking issue. Are you behind a proxy without having it configured in Maven?

Comment: If you rename your .m2 directory, run mvn install and see if the repositories get downloaded. If not, its likely to be a networking issue, if it does work, the metadata may be out of date.

Comment: Thanks for answers, everything is downloaded fine but still has the same error on "Parent"
It's not a proxy issue as I am able to go on the adress, that's weird.

Comment: Your browser is something different than Maven. If you have a proxy/firewall within your area you need to configure that in your settings.xml

Comment: @khmarbaise Alright thanks, it looks like it works now, even if I have an error, it still compile etc ... Weird stuff. 

Thanks anyways.